# how do I find the dual when a variable has an upper bound?

Tags: linear-programming, duality

What is the dual of this primal LP?
$$
max~c^Tx
$$
$$
s.t.~Ax=0
$$
$$
0 \leq x \leq d,~d \in \mathbb{R}_+^n
$$

Comment: Hint: for purposes of deriving the dual, rewrite the bound as an explicit constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can imagine the upper bound for the variable is another constraint.

$\max: c^Tx$

$\text{s.t.}$

$Ax = 0$ --> $π_1$

$x ≤ d$ --> $π_2$

$0 ≤ x$

Therefore, you will obtain the following dual form.
(Assume $A$ is $m \times n$ matrix)

$\min: d^Tπ_2 $

$\text{s.t.}$

$π_1A + π_2 ≥ c$

$π_1 \in \mathbb{R}^m$

$0 ≤ π_2$

Comment: Equality constraints have free duals.

Comment: @RobPratt Thanks for correcting my typo